# Bluetooth mouse extreme lag and disconnect ubuntu 17.04

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I have got a Surface Arch Bluetooth mouse which lags after connecting then disconnects after some time. Is there any fix for this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious? Does it work under other os's? Have you tried new batteries? My bluetooth mouse chews through batteries 10 times more quickly than my other wireless mice with dedicated dongles

Comment: @Will it works on Window flawlessly as well as my PS4. I don't get why Bluetooth pairing is such a problem on Ubuntu. Regarding battery, it lasts for at least 6 months.

Comment: A search online shows a lot of people saying they have to delete and re-pair the device each time they switch from one OS to the other. Seems like it's just a buggy device to get working atm, probably due to the low power magic going on. I'm lucky to get 6 weeks out of my batteries.